# How can I conditionally load a collection mapped in an object?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

Given the following mapping

```
<class name="com.domain.Season" table="cm.pub.jsn_mstr">
    <id name="seasonCode" column="season_code" length="1"/>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="name" length="20"/>
    <set name="promotions" lazy="false">
        <key column="season_code"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.domain.Promotion" not-found="ignore"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

How can I include or exclude the load of `promotions`? I could use `lazy="true"` though I'm using Jackson to serialize the result which is after the session is closed.

```
public Collection<Season> getSeasons(boolean withPromotions) {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        return (List<Season>) session.createQuery("from Season s").list();
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Problem with using lazy loading.

The `getSeasons` method above is used in an MVC controller that will retrieve seasons, then using jackson serialize them to JSON (using Spring/MVC's view-resolver) so I don't actually access the objects myself, therefore any attempt to lazily load the collection results in an exception (as jackson will call an iterator on all collection properties).

Here's an example that shows an exception will get thrown:

```
public Collection<Season> getSeasons(boolean withPromotions) {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    final List<Season> r;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        r = (List<Season>) session.createQuery(
                withPromotions
                ? "from Season s join fetch s.promotions"
                : "from Season s"
                ).list();
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    try {
        for (Season s : r) {
            for (Promotion p : s.getPromotions()) {
                // Exception thrown here as we attempted to get an iterator.
                LOG.debug("Promotion: " + p.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Couldn't get promotions", ex);
    }
    return r;
}
```

And of course this time the mapping needs to have `lazy="true"` otherwise it will always eager read the collection.

```
<class name="com.domain.Season" table="cm.pub.jsn_mstr">
    <id name="seasonCode" column="jsn_seas" length="1"/>
    <set name="promotions" lazy="true">
        <key column="jpr_seas"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.domain.Promotion" not-found="ignore"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

Data type for `promotions` field is `Collection<Promotion>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the only way I could do this is to not map the collection and instead send off two queries, and adding to the collection myself.

This gives me greater control of the association and also improves performance as I'm only sending off two queries instead of 1+n (where n is the rows retrieved from the first query).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
session.createQuery("from Season s join fetch s.promotions").list();
```

From hibernate reference:
A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.

Comment: This is a better query, any idea how to tell hibernate to not try to load the collection when the collection is accessed though? i.e. if I try `season.getPromotions()` after the session has closed it tries to load the promotions, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Stupid hibernate.. I have no idea why this doesn't work for you @BrettRyan. I've made similar queries and I can access the collections through the getters after closing the session without problems. Are you sure that the instance of Season (the one you are calling the getter which throws the exception) is the very same one that is returned from your getSeasons(boolean) function? Am I missing something? You should probably add some more information because both my answer and ManuPk's are valid solutions to the lazy loading issue. Perhaps the culprit lies somewhere else in your code. Good luck.

Comment: +1 well said @buritos. Good to know that **join fetch** will also initialize the collections.

Comment: Just updated question with a piece of code which will throw an exception when accessing the iterator of the given collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Hibernate.initialize()` to initialize a collection from the proxies. In your example, add the below code.

```
public Collection<Season> getSeasons(boolean withPromotions) {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Season> list = session.createQuery("from Season s").list();
        for(Season s : list){
            if(condition){
               Hibernate.initialize(s.getPromotions());
            }
        }
        return list;


    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

From the API docs this will,

*The static methods Hibernate.initialize() and Hibernate.isInitialized(), provide the application with a convenient way of working with lazily initialized collections or proxies. Hibernate.initialize(cat) will force the initialization of a proxy, cat, as long as its Session is still open. Hibernate.initialize( cat.getKittens() ) has a similar effect for the collection of kittens.*

Read the API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization) or an example [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t62077.html).

Comment: This would mean turning the lazy flag on, though this will cause Jackson to throw an exception since the session is closed.

Comment: You should call this method before you close the session. This is the way of dynamically controlling the **Lazy** behavior in hibernate. I have updated my answer with its usage in your method.

Comment: Thanks Manu, I think I'm not describing the problem properly. When the returned seasons are coming back to my controller when Jackson tries to serialize it reads the promotions property causing an exception to be raised as the session is closed.

Comment: I got your problem, Did you tried the above code. If it is not working whats the error you are getting?

Comment: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: package.Season.promotions, no session or session was closed`, the reason for this is I'm not serializing in the service layer, but in the controller via Spring/MVC, it tries to access the `promotions` property and the exception is raised.

Comment: Just thought of a solution, I could `season.setPromotions(Collections.emptySet())`. Not ideal though.

Comment: Scratch that solution, setting the collection causes hibernate to try and delete all the rows in the promotions table.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your problem is Jackson -- reading everything in the bean. Not Hibernate.

Either:

1) **Control Jackson properly,** to transmit the data you actually need -- and avoid what you don't want it to 'pull on'.

2) **Use Spring's 'OpenSessionInViewFilter'** or similar that binds a Session to a thread-local, and leaves it open until the view has run -- enabling Jackson to still 'pull on' & load the collections at view-rendering stage.

3)  **or, Map two different classes** (one full details, one light-weight) to the same table, and retrieve the one you actually need.

SeasonLite could perhaps be an ancestor of Season (full details), but note that you're not mapping inheritance with Hibernate -- you're mapping two separate views of the same table.

*PS: methods like 'getSomeData(boolean retrieveThisData)' appear to be a common anti-pattern. I've seen it many times before.*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is a very late answer, but I only just found your question when looking for something else.

As already stated in some of the answers, the problem is that Hibernate uses a 'placeholder' `PersistentCollection` for a lazy loading collection. To stop Hibernate trying to fill out the collection when it is accessed, you could `null` out the actual `Promotions` list in each of the `Season` entities that are returned by the query. In code, something like this:

```
if (!withPromotions) {
    for (Season s : r) {
        s.setPromotions(null);
    }
}
```

Setting the `Promotions` to null will clear out the reference to the  Hibernate collection object. You should be able to do this outside the session.

What *we* do is create methods on our entities for each of our collections similar to this:

```
public boolean isPromotionsLoaded() {
    if (((promotions instanceof org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection)
            && !((org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection) promotions).wasInitialized())
            || (getPromotions() == null)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then we can use these methods to find out if we can safely access the collection.

Anyway, hope this helps someone.